# How to create a android 2d tool palette, as seen in Androidify?

Tags: android, android-layout, palette

I'm working on an application that does have some similarities with Google's androidify, however what I'm mostly interested in is the 2d tool palette that appears on the sides of the screen in that app (shown in the photos below).

The picture below shows the normal layout without any palette.

[image: This is the layout with the palette closed]

Once the hanger icon is clicked, a 2d tool palette appears. This also causes the view containing the avatar to be resized.

[image: This is the layout after the palette has been opened]

I have looked around the Internet for a while now, but since the concept is fairly new and has only been used in a handful of apps (all by Google I think), there is not much on it. So is there anyone who has implemented this or has an idea how it could be done or even where to get started on it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look for DrawerLayout on dev site. Then use a ListView with custom adapter inflating your views containing necessary tools.

Comment: I think the tool palette on the left side is just a listview.And when we click on an item another view displays on the bottom is a galleryview.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I don't see how your comment is relevant to my situation here?

Comment: @NewOverHere yeah I have been playing around with the draw navigation but to have them both at the same time is the part that gets a little tricky I guess

Comment: COCOS2d is a 2d framework using it you can have smooth animations and object movements on touch event of images

Comment: It's a game engine! which is not really the purpose of this question! the 2d tool palette here is merely a set of native android drawers